# Index a Particular Numeric Vector From a List of Vectors in R

Tags: r, list, vector, indexing, matching

In R, for the sake of example, I have a list composed of equal-length numeric vectors of form similar to:

```
list <- list(c(1,2,3),c(1,3,2),c(2,1,3))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 2

[[3]]
[1] 2 1 3
...
```

Every element of the list is unique. I want to get the index number of the element `x <- c(2,1,3)`, or any other particular numeric vector within the list.

I've attempted using `match(x,list)`, which gives a vector full of NA, and `which(list==(c(1,2,3))`, which gives me a "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" error. Coercing the list to different types didn't seem to make a difference for the which function. I also attempted various grep* functions, but these don't return exact numeric vector matches. Using `find(c(1,2,3),list)` or even some fancy `sapply` which %in% type functions didn't give me what I was looking for. I feel like I have a type problem. Any suggestions?

--Update--
Summary of Solutions

Thanks for your replies. The method in the comment for this question is clean and works well (via akrun).

```
> which(paste(list)==deparse(x))
[1] 25
```

The next method didn't work correctly

```
> which(duplicated(c(x, list(y), fromLast = TRUE)))
[1] 49
> y
[1] 1 2 3
```

This sounds good, but in the next block you can see the problem

```
> y<-c(1,3,2)
> which(duplicated(c(list, list(y), fromLast = TRUE)))
[1] 49
```

More fundamentally, there are only 48 elements in the list I was using.

The last method works well (via BondedDust), and I would guess it is more efficient using an apply function:

```
> which( sapply(list, identical, y ))
[1] 25
```

Comment: Just for fun `which(paste(list)==deparse(x))`

Comment: @akrun - that's a good one

Comment: Nice @akrun. This works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> L <- list(c(1,2,3),c(1,3,2),c(2,1,3))
> sapply(L, identical, c(2,1,3))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> which( sapply(L, identical, c(2,1,3)) )
[1] 3
```

This would be slightly less restrictive in its test:

```
> which( sapply(L, function(x,y){all(x==y)}, c(1:3)) )
[1] 1
```

Comment: This works well. Good idea. I wonder if this is more efficient than the {which(paste(x)==deparse(y))} method? I could clock it, but efficiency isn't a big issue for a single index lookup, even with a large set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `duplicated()`. If we add the matching vector to the end of the original list and set `fromLast = TRUE`, we will find the duplicate(s).  Then we can use `which()` to get the index.

```
which(duplicated(c(list, list(c(2, 1, 3)), fromLast = TRUE))
# [1] 3
```

Or you could add it as the first element and subtract 1 from the result.

```
which(duplicated(c(list(c(2, 1, 3)), list))) - 1L
# [1] 3
```

Note that the type always matters with this type of comparison.  When comparing integers and numerics, you will need to convert doubles to integers for this to run without issue.  For example, `1:3` is not the same type as `c(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: It still unfortunately faces the same difficulties in matching what explicitly should be matched vs. what appears to on the surface match, as per `duplicated(list(1:3,c(1,2,3)))`

Comment: I agree - be specific about things. numeric isn't integer :-)

Comment: Right, integers are key. `duplicated(list(1:3, as.integer(c(1,2,3))))` works.

Answer (score 3):

`match` works fine if you pass it the right data.

```
L <- list(c(1,2,3),c(1,3,2),c(2,1,3))
match(list(c(2,1,3)), L)
#[1] 3
```

Beware that this works via coercing lists to character, so fringe cases will fail - with a hat-tip to @nicola:

```
match(list(1:3),L)
#[1] NA
```

even though:

```
1:3 == c(1,2,3)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Although arguably:

```
identical(1:3,c(1,2,3))
#[1] FALSE

identical(1:3,c(1L,2L,3L))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You always seem to know all the stuff that no one else knows.  I bet I'm not the only one that didn't know `match()` can compare lists.  Nice one

Comment: @RichardScriven - trial and error can make one look smart when they're really not. :-)

Comment: This is very nice to see. But it can be dangerous, since `list`s are coerced to `character`: try `match(list(1:3),L)` and it fails. +1 anyway.

Comment: @RichardScriven - see, I know less than I appear to know. Thanks for pointing out the limitations nicola!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
vapply(list,function(z) all(z==x),TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Enclosing the above line to `which` gives you the index of the list.